# JList not updating with custom ListModel

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a TestListModel which extends AbstractListModel

```
public class TestListModel extends AbstractListModel {
List<Test> testlist = new ArrayList<Test>();

public Object getElementAt(int arg0) {
    return testlist.get(arg0);
}

public int getSize() {
    return testlist.size();
}
public void add(Test t) {
    System.out.println("adding");
    testlist.add(t);
    System.out.println(testlist.toString());
}
public void remove(Test t) {
    testlist.remove(t);
}

}
```

I have a JList like so

```
final TestListModel listModel = new TestListModel();
    listModel.add(new Test("test", "scen"));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final JList list = new JList(listModel);
    panel.add(list);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 400);
```

I also have an Add Button that has an actionlister

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();fc.setCurrentDirectory(new 
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frmAtt);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    listModel.add(getTest(fc.getSelectedFile().toString()));
}
}
```

The ArrayList appears to be updating when I add another test through the button but the GUI does not reflect this change. JList appears completely blank. It should be showing all the tests in the model.

Only the first test "scen" shows up in the JList which I added manually to the list (can see in the code above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not firing any of the notification methods after changing the ListModel's data. The solution is to of course do this. Look at the AbstractListModel API at the methods that start with `fireXXX(...)` and call the appropriate one inside of your model whenever data is changed. i.e., in these methods:

```
public void add(Test t) {
    testlist.add(t);
    int index0 = testlist.size() - 1;
    int index1 = index0;
    fireIntervalAdded(this, index0, index1);
}

public void remove(Test t) {
    int index0 = ... // this will depend on where t was in the testlist
    int index1 = ... // ditto
    testlist.remove(t);
    fireIntervalRemoved(this, index0, index1);
}
```

The reason to call these methods is because the model must notify its listeners that the data has been changed, else the listeners (your JList component) will not change their view of the data.

Comment: Indeed, (and if he keeps it that way not recommended), he could just repaint himself.

Comment: @rimero please clarify your comment.

Comment: I see! I am just getting familiar with Swing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would my add method look like so

public void add(Test t) {
  testlist.add(t);
  
  fireIntervalAdded(this, getSize()-2, getSize()-1);
 }

I'm not quite sure about the second and third parameter in fire method.

Comment: Thank you for further clarification! What are both index0 and index1 the same in add and remove method?

Comment: @Aman: You will want to read the API to see exactly what they represent, but if you are adding or removing only 1 item, then yes, they are the same value.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I meant that your solution is the most appropriate, as he didn't fire events. If let's say he implemented directly a ListModel, he would have had to repaint the list himself. Without having your answer, he could also have tried a repaint and he would have noticed that values are reflected in the JList... Hope it's clear enough.